# TypeScript: using instanceof with and without "===true"

Tags: typescript, instanceof

Let's consider this simple statement :

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

if (foo instanceof Element) {
    a.innerHTML = "Some text";
}
```

But if you write :

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

if (foo instanceof Element === true) {
    a.innerHTML = "Some text";
}
```

The TypeScript transpiler throws an error :

```
'foo' is possibly 'null'.
```

Assuming that instanceof can return only true of false, I don't see why the transpiler doesn't accept the condition with === true.
Same error with the opposite statement :

```
!(foo instanceof Element)
```

is not the same than :

```
foo instanceof Element === false
```

What is the reason of this behaviour ? Is there any difference between the 2 statements ?

Comment: TypeScript's [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) behavior only occurs for specific sorts of syntactic constructs, deemed common enough to be worth spending the compiler resources checking. `=== false` is not one of these, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#9508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9508). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Basically there is zero benefit to being explicit over the usual truthiness mechanics here.

Comment: @jcalz : thank you for the "official" explanation I didn't find about type guard not working with === true. I think you can post this answer. If however we would like to use === true, is there any other solution in the following code than (foo as Element).innerHtml = "Some text"; to avoid an error from the transpiller ?

Comment: @JaredSmith: I agree that on this example foo instanceof Element === true is unusefully too verbose. But how about a statement like this !(foo instanceof Element) && !(bar instanceof Element). For me, this is less clear than foo instanceof Element === false && bar instanceof Element === false.

Comment: @RoarS.: I wasn't able to find in the official documentation the possible return values of instanceof. Is it really possible to get null as return value ?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  (No, `null` is not possible, and TS doesn't expect `null` there; not sure what RoarS meant).  No, there is currently no way to make the compiler understand `=== true` or `=== false` as a narrowing syntax, at least not that's any easier than just doing the truthy/falsy check in the first place.

Comment: @Mulot: I couldn't reproduce your case on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play, hence I believe your finding in doc is correct. BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's [narrowing / type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) support only applies to certain coding patterns.  The type checker cannot afford to analyze code by simulating every possible logical implication of the code flow; instead it uses heuristics to detect common conventions that are used in practice as type guards. They have to be common, so that the benefits of narrowing outweigh the cost incurred by performing additional checks everywhere. (See [this unpopular comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275#issuecomment-576819328) by the TS team dev lead on microsoft/TypeScript#26275, for example.)

There's an older issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#9508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9508) where it is proposed that `expr === true` and `expr === false` behave as type guards in the same situations where `expr` and `!expr` would behave as type guards.  This was closed as "won't fix" [because](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9508#issuecomment-260504948) "in most cases `=== true` is a code smell and doesn't appear often enough to justify the extra complexity to support it."

On the other hand, there's an issue at [microsoft/TypeSript#31105](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31105) asking for the same thing, and it's marked as a bug. It's on [the Backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/29), meaning that nobody is necessarily going to work on it.  However, the TS folks are often receptive to accepting pull requests from the community for such Backlog issues, so that means the best way to see this change would be for an interested party to submit an appropriate pull request.

Until and unless such support is implemented, the easiest way to proceed is to simply perform the more conventional checks of `expr` and `!expr`, like `if (foo instanceof Element)` or `if (!(foo instanceof Element))`. Anything else would be more complicated or fragile (e.g., writing a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates))